# Galaxy S2 not recognized by computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb

When I try to connect my Galaxy S2 device to my computer via USB, I get an error saying that the device has malfunctioned and is unrecognized. It appears as "Unknown device" in device manager.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this from my Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus and it worked:

1. From your mobile, click **MENU > SETTINGS > APPLICATIONS > DEVELOPMENT**
2. **UNTICK USB debugging, Stay Awake, Allow mock locations**
3. Insert USB cable from mobile to PC/laptop > "**Enable USB debugging**" > OK
4. Drag down the the USB icon from the upper left part of the screen
5. Tap on "**Connect USB**" > "**Connect to USB storage**"
6. Then, automatically, your PC/laptop will now detect new mobile/sd device
7. **From the laptop/PC**, select "**Open folder to view files**"
8. There, you'll see MEMORY CARD storage and MOBILE storage as "Removable Disk..." (mine is G)
9. You should now be able to transfer files from PC>mobile and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what the others have already answered, if you just want to access the files on the phone's storage and SD card, you can just mount the file system.

Unplug the USB cable, then **Settings > Wireless and network > USB utilities > Connect storage to PC**

Answer (score 1):

try to key in this in dialer

*#7284#

it has 4 option there..

UART
MODEM
PDA
USB
MODEM
PDA

For usb. select the PDA.if it already selected to PDA. reselect it by select MODEM and then PDA again.. Only change the USB setting.. andthen press back. try reconnect to kies again..
hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be because you dont have the  neceasary drivers. Make sure you have the `USB debugging mode` ON for your device. Then use `Samsung Kies`, a software like itunes, to detect your device.

Comment: Downloaded these drivers: http://www.mediafire.com/?8jq83u3xs6w8jou and enabled debugging mode and still no go

Comment: You don't need to download those drivers. Just download Samsung Kies. It has the inbuilt drivers necessary to detect your phone.

Comment: I reinstalled Kies twice and my phone still doesn't get recognized at all. Kies doesn't even know that it's plugged in, and I'm getting the same unrecognized device problem.

Comment: As far as i know, there are two more things you can do. One is to check whether the USB mode is set to Samsung Kies when you connect your device to the PC. Only then, Kies will detect your device. If you have already tried this, the last option is to take your phone to a service center and have them check it for you.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. So I took my phone to a service center, and now all I have left to do is wait.

Comment: Hmmm. Do let me know what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that USB Debugging mode is on?

Under `Settings > Applications > Development` you should see an option for `USB Debugging` -- if that isn't checked you won't be able to mount your phone.

Comment: Tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try to solve this in two ways either you can download Samsung Kies and using that you can connect your phone , or if not by that way then u can check in your phone that is your USB Debugging On its in settings Option > Application > Development see that is it checked or not, if its checked then it means its on..

You Can also Download PDA NET and install in your PC thats also one of the way if you dont want to install Samsung Kies

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I was so annoyed that I did a factory reset. It clears all your data, but it also solved my issue.

Comment: without any troubleshooting first?

Answer (score 0):

When windows sees it as "the device has malfunctioned" it is a different issue than when it says "drivers were not installed, your device may not work properly. "  If it says "malfunction" it is a problem with the usb hardware connections themselves,  albeit the cable end or the device port. Try using some electrical contact cleaner and a soft tooth brush and the clear the port with a compressed air duster can. Just spray a little of the cleaner on the brush and gently clean your port and/or cable. Then spray area just enough to dry with air duster. Worked well for me. If you take it to a service shop they will do it for you for a minimal fee.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob as my S3 is not deteced on my MAC , but it is very easy to solve:

1. Connect your S2 to your PC using a datacable
2. Now in your phone, go to *Settings→More→USB Utilities*
3. Turn on USB mass storage button.

It works.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it so strange that on some computer config it is not a problem??? In many cases a third party software is the badass ( e.g. firewall, antivirus apps.) Always try on another machine before you go back to the shop:-)

Comment: not a very good answer.... re-edit to improve your answer...