# Lots of "Input/output error" after connecting Samsung Galaxy S2 via USB

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, linux

I'm trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-9100, Android 2.3.4, I9100XXKI1) with my Linux box (Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric).

I'm using the USB storage mode (Settings ➔ Wireless and network ➔ USB utilities).

The device is recognized and two device nodes in `/dev` are created.

In the syslog, I see this output:

```
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] 62325760 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.7 GiB)
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 c8 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1224
quiet_error: 98 callbacks suppressed
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 153
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 146
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 147
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 148
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 149
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 150
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 151
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 152
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 153
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 154
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] 24133632 512-byte logical blocks: (12.3 GB/11.5 GiB)
 sdg:
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 10 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 32
 sdg:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
 sdg:
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
 sdg:
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 32
 sdg:
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
quiet_error: 56 callbacks suppressed
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 146
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 147
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 148
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 149
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 150
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 151
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 152
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 153
Buffer I/O error on device sdh, logical block 154
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 a8 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 424
Buffer I/O error on device sdg, logical block 53
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 512
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 32
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdg, sector 4096
sdg: detected capacity change from 12356419584 to 0
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Media Changed
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Power on, reset, or bus device reset occurred
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
 sdh:
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
usb 1-1.5: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 48 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 04 90 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 1168
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 24
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] Device not ready
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh]  Add. Sense: Medium not present
sd 9:0:0:1: [sdh] CDB: Read(10): 28 20 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sdh, sector 24
```

When I try to list the root folder, I get:

```
ls: cannot access /media/3CB1-07D3/Samsung: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /media/3CB1-07D3/LOST.DIR: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /media/3CB1-07D3/external_sd: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /media/3CB1-07D3/usbStorage: Input/output error
...
```

I tried to [reset the USB connection mode using PhoneUtil](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/my-samsung-galaxy-3-gt-i5801-is-not-being-detected-in-my-pc-what-should-i-d/5067#5067) but that didn't help. I tried to manually mount the phone with the same result.

Then I tried to [enable USB debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17757/5167). In this case, syslog says:

```
usb 1-1.5: new high speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
scsi10 : usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
Jan 11 10:24:23 host mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
Jan 11 10:24:23 host mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 11 was not an MTP device
cdc_acm 1-1.5:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
cdc_acm 1-1.5:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
Jan 11 10:24:24 host modem-manager[1288]: <info>  (ttyACM0) opening serial port...
scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Android    UMS Composite    00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
scsi 10:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Android    UMS Composite    00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
sd 10:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
sd 10:0:0:1: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

When trying to mount `/dev/sdg`, I get `mount: no medium found on /dev/sdh`

I dimly remember that this once worked using the USB storage mode. In the meantime, I installed a firmware update. Any idea what I could try next?

Unrelated questions:

- [Unable to mount Galaxy S2 on Debian Squeeze laptop as storage device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17660/unable-to-mount-galaxy-s2-on-debian-squeeze-laptop-as-storage-device): In my case, the device is recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu is very outofdate. 12.03 12.10. 13.04. 13.10 14.04 are all newer versions of Ubuntu.Use 14.04 or newer when possible

Since 13 issues with my S2 sdcard are almost nonexistent

Comment: I don't have the phone anymore but I remember that since 13.xx, the USB connection worked most of the time. Of course, now I have an S4 and new problems (MTP support ;-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Enable ums (universal mass storage I think) in settings storage.Ive this enabled and it works perfectly (but I dont know why I get option connect usb storage on android) but when USB debugging turned on (I reverse tether) I get a mtp error and i have to find it buried under windows and close it to access the phone storage on pc

Comment: @AaronDigulla HAHHAAHA LOL i just saw this is 2yrs old!

Comment: I'd need to root my device for UMS. I'm not that desperate, yet :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla its worth rooting it

Answer (score 0):

I barely remember similar symptoms caused by a defect SD-card but that doesn't explain the problems with both virtual devices. Did you try a different cable and a different USB-port on the computer side? Just to make sure the problem is not caused by a bad cable connection ...

Comment: Uups, should have checked the questions date first ... :-D

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are enabling USB transfer mode in the S2 USB options. Works fine for me that way.
More settings > USB utilities > mass storage.

Comment: NOT IF usb debugging because of an mtp error message blocking you fromclicking open phone directory